# ¿Como eliminar la cuenta regresiva del comando 'TIMEOUT' en Windows?

Tags: windows, cmd, timeout

Estoy haciendo un sencillo launcher para juegos que muestre textos y mensajes en la ventana del Símbolo del Sistema de Windows (CMD), y por eso estoy utilizando el comando *timeout* para que estos mensajes tengan cierto tiempo en la pantalla, pero la pantalla se sobrecarga con los mensajes *esperando x segundos, presione una tecla para continuar* y pues, quisiera saber si hay una forma para que el **conteo no se muestre en la pantalla** o **para omitir este texto.**

Quiero dar las gracias por haber leido hasta aqui y también para aquellas personitas que hayan respondido.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para evitar que el `ECHO` de los comandos sea visible en la consola puedes usar `> NUL`.

*Este comando hará esperar 5 segundos sin mostrar ningún mensaje de texto.*

```
TIMEOUT 5 > NUL
```

Si por otro lado deseas visualizar un mensaje u otra cosa al terminar la espera, puedes concatenar un segundo comando con `&&`.

*Este comando hará esperar 5 segundos y mostrará un mensaje.*

```
TIMEOUT 5 > NUL && ECHO Pasaron los 5 segundos
```

También puedes usar otras cosas en lugar de `ECHO`, como por ejemplo `PAUSE` que pedirá presionar `enter` para continuar, entre otros.